# MYSQL Joomla database call not functioning correctly

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I am having an issue with a database call within Joomla whereas I am looping though an array to pull all records if there is a matching value LIKE that array value.

Here is my code:

```
$time = JRequest::getVar('time');

    if($time == 'Morning') {
        $times = array('07', '08', '09', '10', '11');
    }
    if($time == 'Afternoon') {
        $times = array('12', '13', '14', '15', '16');

    }
    if($time == 'Evening') {
        $times = array('17', '18', '19', '20', '21');
    }
    if(isset($times)) {
        $first = array_shift($times);
        $query->where('a.startTime LIKE "%'. $first .'%"');
        foreach($times as $tim => $val) {               
            $query->or('a.startTime LIKE "%'. $val .'%"');
        }
    }
    $query->order('a.weekday,a.startTime ASC');

    return $query;
```

If time equals 'Morning' I only want it to return records that have the values that are in the 'Morning' array.
I am having an issue with the 'or' part of my query. I don't think the '$query->or' is a valid function?
I want the query to execute "WHERE a.startTime LIKE arrayvalue1 OR LIKE arrayvalue2....etc" but am unsure how to do this using the Joomla database queries.
Thanks

Comment: why substring-wildcard searches? wouldn't it simply be easier to do `HOUR(a.startTime) BETWEEN $min and $max`?

Comment: You should be name quoting a.startTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forget to add these line in your query at the beginning:

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*');
```

For more details go this link:
[JDatabaseQuery](http://docs.joomla.org/API16%3aJDatabaseQuery)

Comment: Hey! Sorry I do have that in my code already I just didn't put it in my example. Apologies.

Comment: And just saw the link to the documentation so thanks for that! :)

Comment: in which case, can you please put your full query code on your question, just incase that is what is causing the problem ;)